DAX/Power BI: How do I create a burndown column/table?
I have the expected number of items to close on each day in Date ECD, and another column for the actual amount closed on each day in Date ACD. So I have a table with one column having every day between 1/1/2023 and 12/31/2025. Below is a snippet of the table with data:



Date
Date ECD
Date ACD




5/11/24
1
1


5/12/24
0
0


5/13/24
2
1


5/14/24
1
2


5/15/24
1
0


5/16/24
0
1



The issue is creating two Burndown columns, that take a sum of ALL values in DATE ECD and DATE ACD, then reduces it by the value in the corresponding column each day. The burndown ECD can go on through to 12/31/2025, but once it hits 0, it should have #N/A as the rest of the values (this stops the graph from showing 0 after the burndown is complete). The Burndown ACD starts at the sum of Burndown ECD, and reduces every day there is a value in Date ACD, but should give a value of #N/A for every day AFTER today (or after it hits 0). Let's say today is 5/13/2024. The burndown table should look like this:



Date
Date ECD
Date ACD
Burndown ECD
Burndown ACD




5/11/24
0
0
6
6


5/12/24
2
1
4
5


5/13/24
2
2
2
3


5/14/24
1

1
#N/A


5/15/24
1

0
#N/A


5/16/24
0

#N/A
#N/A



Thank you for your help!
I tried a few different measures, calculates, filters, sums, from other places online and Chat GPT and nothing has worked. Other solutions to similar problems did not produce the result I wanted.
